# Best way for storing and querying DateTime in Azure CosmosDB

Tags: indexing, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

Currently I work on indexing documents in Azure Cosmos DB SQL API. I read here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates

that date type could be stored as a string or numeric value as Unix timestamp.

There are several advantages when using string format `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffZ` like e.g. human readable, but there is not written directly that this is also more performant when querying.

So we can use string range index or numeric range index for epoch time.

Does someone know what is faster for querying - range filters operations?

e.g. `startTime > x and  startTime < y`

or in udf in similar way when taking into account only hour
e.g.

```
function somefunc(ts, firstHour, secondHour) {
    var ts_date = new Date(ts);
    var hour = ts_date.getHours();
    return hour >= firstHour && hour < secondHour;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/working-with-dates ?

Comment: @Matias Quaranta you did not read my post, I checked.

Comment: My bad, I missed the link being the same :)

Comment: Any specific sense of "faster" you're looking for? Very likely the query latency will not change based on the choice here. In general, numbers are more efficient to handle than strings, but for me the readability alone is enough to to use ISO 8601 everywhere.

Comment: @Noah Stahl That is also my feeling. For quering I can also use functions which transforms epoch time into readable format. I will have so many documents, so I will stay with timestamp.